# jqgrid paging in edit form

Tags: forms, jqgrid, navigation, edit

I need to forbid paging to user (nothing should happen on pressing next, prev buttons).
I have found  `onPaging: function (b) {...}` event with returning 'stop' string. But this works only for the grid. Not for the edit form. When I print param, getting 'user' value all the time. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use [viewPagerButtons: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) property of the form editing:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {/*options of navGrid*/},
    {viewPagerButtons: false},    // options of Edit form
    {viewPagerButtons: false});   // options of Add form
```

Comment: Not exectly. The idea is to submit edit form by pressing navigation buttons. That's easy. I'm doing it into "onclickPgButtons" by clicking "sData" button. But I need to check if there were errors in fields. That's battle I won by checking is "FormError" existance. And now we came to the last problem - even if there were errors, edit form fills with next record. And I want to prevent it, just stay on current.

Comment: @user1169483: I personally don't like the idea with submitting on form navigation so I don't answered your previous question. Current processing of (see [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.formedit.js#L1132-1170)) is not oriented on stopping of scrolling and to continue the scrolling after the submit. So to implement what you need you will have to **overwrite** the `'click'` events of scrolling and continue scrolling somewhere inside of `afterComplete`. So you will have very long and complex code for a simple new feature which is not really required.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You gave me a clue for the next move.

Answer (score 0):

In editOptions : { viewPagerButtons:false }  This is for Previous and Next button on Edit form